# Como modificar o texto vindo do banco de dados?

Tags: php, mysql

Então, quando eu faço a requisição do texto no banco de dados através desta instrução em php `<?=converte($linha['DESCRICAO_PARA_WEB'], 0)?>` o texto é apresentado todo em bloco sem as quebras de linha. Essa função **converte** consiste na alteração de acentuação do texto e acho que não influencia em nada. Eis a função:

```
# Função para conversão de caracteres
function converte($string, $tp){
    if ($tp == "1") 
    $palavra = strtr(utf8_encode($string) ,
    "àáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùüúþÿ" ,"ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÜÚÞß");
    elseif ($tp == "0")
    $palavra = strtr(utf8_encode($string) ,
    "ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÜÚÞß","àáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùüúþÿ");
    return $palavra;
}
```

Conforme ia dizendo o texto é apresentado desta forma no banco de dados mas ao solicitá-lo, ele vem em bloco sem as quebras de linha. Como fazer com que o `PHP` possa considerar estas quebras de linha e apresentá-las conforme mostrado no banco?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para transformar quebras de linha(`\n`) em `<br>` use a função [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.nl2br.php)

```
<?php
$str =  "IMPERDÍVEL!

Localizada no melhor endereço do Chácara
das Pedras em rua plana e de fácil acesso.

Casa aconchegante,";

echo nl2br($str);
```

Saída do navegador: (ver a opção exibir código fonte)

```
IMPERDÍVEL!<br />
<br />
 Localizada no melhor endereço do Chácara<br />
 das Pedras em rua plana e de fácil acesso.<br />
<br />
 Casa aconchegante,
```

[**Exemplo**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/jb9x-7qks)